# Can you request a driver's info via Uber API?

Tags: uber-api

Can you request a driver's car make/model, name, location, and rating via Uber API?

Answer (score 2):

When a user is on a trip, all of that information is available to you (with regards to the driver who is currently giving the user a ride) when you request the status of the users trip: https://developer.uber.com/docs/v1-requests-current

If you're asking wether that information can be obtained about the user themselves (if they are also a driver), that feature is not currently supported by the Uber API.